# How can I create a new pandas column based on the max value of other pandas columns and the associated string column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
id    pred_1    conf_1   pred_2    conf_2   pred_3    conf_3
1     dog         .5       cat       .7      fish       .3
2     cat         .1       fish      .8      dog        .4
3     fish        .7       pig       .3      cat        .6
```

I want to create a new column `most likely` that generates the prediction with the highest confidence level. Ie: for row 1, conf_2 is highest, so value for `most_likely` column is "cat".

I tried:

```
def highest_confidence(row):
  if max(row.p1_conf, row.p2_conf, row.p3_conf) == row.p1_conf:
    row["most_likely"] = row.p1
elif max(row.p1_conf, row.p2_conf, row.p3_conf) == row.p2_conf:
    row["most_likely"] = row.p2
else:
    row["most_likely"] = row.p3


images.apply(highest_confidence, axis=1)
```

but got error: `IndexError: index 13 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 13`

Comment: Did my answer help you with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Given a dataframe like this where the pairs of prediction / confidence are next to each other,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

values = ["dog", "cat", "fish", "pig"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "pred_1": random.sample(values, 4),
    "conf_1": np.random.random(4),
    "pred_2": random.sample(values, 4),
    "conf_2": np.random.random(4),
    "pred_3": random.sample(values, 4),
    "conf_3": np.random.random(4)    
})
```

We can create a temporary dataframe from this that will just be `True` / `False` depending on whether the cell value is the max value for the row:

```
bool_matrix = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis="index")
```

Then we can shift the original dataframe one column to the right to match the booleans. Note that by default shifting happens to the next column of the same type so we have to convert numbers to strings:

```
shifted = df.astype(str).shift(periods=1, axis="columns")
```

And finally, we go through each column, filter and concatenate:

```
hits = []
for column in shifted.columns:
    hits.append(shifted.loc[bool_matrix[column], column])

df["most_likely"] = pd.concat(hits)
```

Since we avoid iterating over rows, it should be reasonably fast.